# Install any alpha, beta, rc version of a package.

Tags: composer-php

How can I install alpha, beta, rc channels of a package without bounding to a specific version?
Suppose I have a package which current version is 0.5.4 and there is an ongoing developing version which isn't current. The versions follow as:
`1.0.0-alpha1`, `1.0.0-alpha.2`, `1.0.0-beta.3`, `1.0.0-beta.2`, `1.0.0-rc.1`, `1.0.0-rc.2`.

#### How can I specify versions for  these 2 scenraios:

1- Installing any 1.0.0 packages updaing on alpha, beta, rc upgrades.

Am I correct assuming speciying version **`1.0.x@dev`**
2- Installing any 1.x packages while installing intermediate alpha, beta packages.

Would this format suffice **`^1.0.0@dev`**?